FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app). in flutter
I'm trying to run my flutter app on chrome for web. But every time I run my flutter code. Its encountering the following error.


I have added google-services.json to <Project>/android/app/
My app running without any error on my physical device and emulator in app version

My problem is only with web of this flutter code. In others platform (Android, Windows etc), the code is working fine
The code in main.dart
import 'package:attandance_seventh/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:attandance_seventh/globals/bindings.dart';
import 'package:attandance_seventh/services/remote/firestore/notification.dart';
import 'package:attandance_seventh/views/launch_screen/launch_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await ScreenUtil.ensureScreenSize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await initNotification();
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return GetMaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          initialBinding: GlabalBindings(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          // home: const SplashScreen(),
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Hello kids'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


The code in index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="attandance_seventh">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>attandance_seventh</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
 
  <!-- <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script> -->
  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
 <script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-app.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "<-------- My API Key---------->",
    authDomain: "<-------- Auth Domain---------->",
    projectId: "<-------- Project ID---------->",
    storageBucket: "<-------- Storage Bucket---------->",
    messagingSenderId: "<-------- Messaging SenderId---------->",
    appId: "<-------- App Id---------->"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
</body>
</html>


Please help me!!!

Try without options parameter.

@HarshSureja, Same error.

upgrade firebase dependencies manually.

Have done. But didn't help

Does this answer your question? No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase

Have you managed to resolve this? Getting the same error for Web only and the other solutions makes no difference

No brother. Couldn't solve yet

You can Specify the Options value.
options: const FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "AIzaSyD3ZbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX",
            authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
            projectId: "XXXXXXX",
            storageBucket: "XXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXX",
            appId: "1:XXXXXX:web:XXXXXXXX",
            measurementId: "G-XXXXXXX")


No bro. I directly tried to use Option values on main(Firebase initialization) as you are saying. Gives exactly same error.
